# Insecure content blocked

Tags: google-chrome, scripting, unsafe

When I published my site, I always get a safety shield in the url-bar on top (using Chrome) that says: Insecure content blocked. This page is trying to load scripts from unauthenticated sources. Because of this error, my site does not show icons or the correct font until I click "load unsafe scripts".

[image: Click to see the pop-up]

Also, there's a certificate for https but when I load the scripts it's automaticly http. How do I fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when you have `http` links/urls in your website. Either change them to `https` urls/links or remove them. Then the error will disappear.

Comment: Omg, thanks! I changed all the cdn's like bootstrap, fontawesome from http to https and poof, problem gone!